# Linked Lists Structures

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

```
typedef struct numbers{
int number_inserted;
struct numbers *next;
}NUMBERS;


int main(){
NUMBERS * num=NULL
int i=0;

while(i<5){
   num=add_number(num);
   i++;
}
}

NUMBERS * add_number(NUMBERS *num){


if (num== NULL) {
    num = (NUMBERS *) malloc(sizeof(NUMBERS));
    num->number_inserted=0;
    num->next = NULL;
}

int gets;
printf("Insira o numero");
scanf("%d",&gets);
num->number_inserted=gets;
num->next = ????????

return num;
}
```

How can I link my variable num->next for my structure NUMBERS so when it is called again I dont lose the numbers I have inserted previously.

Comment: You defined the function add_number  inside main. It is not a standard C feature.

Comment: already fixed that minor error, but that not my main issue

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also it seems you defined the function `add_number` inside the main (if you did not omit the closing brace for main). The C Standard does not allow to declare a function inside another function.

Usually if a singly-linked one-sided list is declared then nodes to the list are added to its beginning.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how new nodes can be added to the beginning and the end of a singly linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct numbers
{
    int number_inserted;
    struct numbers *next;
} NUMBERS;


int add_number_front( NUMBERS **numbers, int x  )
{
    NUMBERS *tmp = malloc( sizeof( NUMBERS ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->number_inserted = x;
        tmp->next = *numbers;

        *numbers = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

int add_number_back( NUMBERS **numbers, int x  )
{
    NUMBERS *tmp = malloc( sizeof( NUMBERS ) );
    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        tmp->number_inserted = x;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        while ( *numbers != NULL ) numbers = &( *numbers )->next;

        *numbers = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}


void display_numbers( NUMBERS **numbers )
{
    for ( NUMBERS *current = *numbers; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->number_inserted );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    NUMBERS *numbers = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) add_number_back( &numbers, i );

    display_numbers( &numbers );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) add_number_front( &numbers, i );

    display_numbers( &numbers );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4
```